# Setting Up A Local Dev Enviroment

Tags: permissions, apache2

I am making a failed attempt at setting up a local development environment on my computer. I have successfully install Ubuntu on a 1TB drive and installed several other things to help my get going. The last thing that is confugaling me (That is how I say confusing :-) ) is how to make it so that Filezilla can download files from my VPS to my /var/www folder. I can download them to my /home/ directory no problem, but the permission system in Ubuntu is a little confusing.

Comment: try `sudo chown $USER:$USER /var/www`

Comment: After you download the files to your home directory you can copy them to /var/www by using sudo on the cp command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ubuntu, then it would be more convenient to use SCP or even RSYNC to get file from remote server. Terminal is really your bestfriend in linux!

Normal usage for using scp would be

```
scp user@remoteserver:/path/of/the/file /path/for/local
```

Here is one for rsync as well

```
rsync -avzu user@remoteserver:/path/of/the/file /path/for/local
```

Read the manual for more information about [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) and [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).